# EF Core 6 to 7 the collections no longer have setters

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core

After upgrading from .net core 6 to 7 and rolling forward all the libraries, after scaffolding the database(we use db first) a lot of the generated properties no longer have setters. These were present before and heavily used. I was looking for options on the scaffold command to include setters or any alternative method to make sure this happens

EF Core 6

```
public virtual ICollection<AccountsPurchaseInvoiceLines> AccountsPurchaseInvoiceLines { get; set; } = new List<AccountsPurchaseInvoiceLines>();
```

EF Core 7

```
public virtual ICollection<AccountsPurchaseInvoiceLines> AccountsPurchaseInvoiceLines { get; } = new List<AccountsPurchaseInvoiceLines>();
```

The lack of the setter on all the entities is the problem. I can go and add manually to get the project building again but I can't find a way to make sure next time I generate the entities the setters remain.

Thanks

Comment: Why do you need setters in a DB first project? EF will set the collections for you.

Comment: setters are being used through out the project to add records to the database

Comment: Not sure you understand what the setter is here. It doesn't allow or forbid you to add records. Once the list created, you do not work with the AccountsPurchaseInvoiceLines, but with the list referenced by it. And you are free to do with the list items anything you want.

Comment: so in EF 6 you can grab an invoice and simply invoice.purchaseline.add(new line) then save the changes.  That is being used through the site and in EF 7 the setter is missing for that property so rather than re write the 1000's of inserts I am hoping to get a quick fix for it today by reverting back to the previous scaffold end result

Comment: `invoice.purchaseline.add(new line)` - there is not a single use of the setter.

Comment: if you were to be given a collection elsewhere you could do invoice.purchaseline = (the new collection received)

Comment: The idea of EF that the only list under the purchaseline is the db table.

Comment: It's ok I wasn't really able to explain why the setters were being used satisfactorily but I have indeed for instance this line s.SupplierEmails = sc.SupplierEmails.Where(x => x.CompanyId == _sfu.CompanyId && x.SupplierId == s.SupplierId).ToList(); i'm guessing now you are suggesting to use AddRange instead and clear the list first but there are definitely hundreds of areas like that I will need to update but for today I really was just looking for a way to reinstate the setters.  I should have just asked elsewhere, I have found the option I needed.  Thanks for trying

Comment: @user174634 that makes sense now seeing your latest comment. Would have bee good to include in the original question to help understand why it was needed.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Take a look at the documentation.
[Customizing the model](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/managing-schemas/scaffolding/?tabs=dotnet-core-cli#customizing-the-model).

> Starting in EF7, you can also use T4 text templates to customize the generated code.

[Customize the entity types](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/managing-schemas/scaffolding/templates?tabs=dotnet-core-cli#customize-the-entity-types).

Add a setter to the T4 template.

Answer (score 1):

You do not need setters here.

In a DB first project, EF will set the collections for you.

You don't use setters to add to collections, you use getters to get the collection then add to the retrieved collection using the add method.

`MyCollection.Add(myEntry);` and `MyEntity.MyCollection.Add(myEntry);` do not use any setters - they use a getter and an add method.

If you use setters to add to collections then you are replacing the whole collection each time instead of just adding to them.

If your code needs the setter for some reason, it is doing something very wrong.

---

If you want to get the setters back just to avoid rewriting a load of code then you could simply have to downgrade back to EF Core 6.

Update:

After seeing Alexander Petrov's answer, it looks like you can also customise the model using T4 text templates.

Comment: I just need the setter to avoid re writing large parts of the project right now

Comment: So you are supremely confident they have completely removed setters then.  For instance you might create a company object and add it's child entries by companyobject.address.add() , this no longer viable as the address has lost it's setter and therefore you can not call the Add function on the collection. I don't imagine have a set on a property is that unusual.

Comment: That would not use a setter...

Comment: Tell you once again, you don't really understand the difference between a pointer and the list pointed by the pointer.

Comment: Ok,  that comment just doesn't really do much to help.  But I guess... cheers ..

Comment: Is there a problem when you run the code? Maybe you should ask a question about a specific problem or error you are experiencing.

Comment: The main question on how to reinstate setters was ignored in favour of a bit of ridicule. This has now been resolved though (thankfully as I don't have the time right now to make the correct changes)

Comment: @YungDeiza Both last two statements in the "answer" are wrong. First off, they don't need to downgrade to EFC6, they can customize the scaffolding template - see the answer by [Alexander Petrov](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5045688/alexander-petrov). Second, judging that having setter is "something very wrong" is highly opinionated. They existed in all previous "classic" EF and "modern" EF Core, and many people find them useful, especially with C# object initializers which do not allow calling `Add` (or any) method of member, but assigning them with collection initializer.

Comment: @user174634 it was not ridicule, I don't think anyone could see why you would need the setters i.e. you did not show any error you had experienced or any code that would need them.

Comment: @Ivan Stoev, if you are using a setter to add to simply add to a collection then, yes, you are doing something very wrong.

Comment: @YungDeiza As I said, this is just your opinion which many people disagree. And SO is not for opinions, but solutions of the problems of our colleagues, so let be respectful to OP wishes. If you maintain a big long time codebase, you would understand OP and my point.

Comment: It's my bad I didn't explain why these were reqiured but I did understand why we needed the setters and usually when they release a new version for EF Core there is quite often an option you can pass to the scaffold command to revert to previous behaviour until you can address the required changes in a timely fashion. Which is all sorted now. For instance they also changed to so a valid SSL is now required which on the dev server there isn't. However instead of use the option in the connection string I did opt to install a real SSL cert on the server using https://letsencrypt.org/

Comment: _"then you could simply have to downgrade back to EF 6"_ I hope you mean EF **Core** 6... EF6 is really old... Anyhow, downgrading is not the way to go, because the old one goes out of support.

Comment: @JHBonarius yes, Core 6 not just 6