# Using reverse engeneering with Scaffold-DBContext, makes virtual collections read-only

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core, scaffolding, ef-core-7.0

Using EF Core 7, after scaffolding, the generated code looks like this:

```
public partial class Category
{
    public Guid CategoryId { get; set; }
    public Guid Title { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<Product> Products { get; } = new List<Product>(); // <= setter missing here
}
```

As you can see, Products is read-only, which was not in previous versions of EF. The problem is that I can't fill it when creating a Category object:

```
Category cat = new Category()
{
    CategoryId = Guid.NewGuid(),
    Title = "",
    Products = new List<Products>() {/* ... */} // <= Error happens here
}
```

it also happens when I'm going to customize the Products of a Category which are returned from database. The solution is to add setter in class model definition, but it will be deleted next time I scaffold and it's hard to manage. Is there any solution, or I need to turn back to EF5, or wait a while for fix?

Comment: Have you considered using `cat.Products.AddRange(...)` instead? then there would not be a need to reassign the list

Comment: Yes, I do. But in this case, I can't use it in Selects and use it the same like the question. We have a huge projects with lots of these cases. We have unlimited errors after updating to EF7

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/74599932/5045688