# Scaffolding in EF7 no longer produce 'setter'

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core

I was trying to upgrade a personal projet of mine from .Net 6 to 7 (mostly to find out about breaking changes). As such, I expected stuff that would need rework (it is always the case!). The project is for a non-profit if at some point I dare to finish it, which is far from being the case at the moment.

As the context now: I am managing a form containing categories (with categories having questions). Both categories and questions have an Order property so the user can reorder them if they did not created them in the right position in the first place (or if they forgot one along the way).

As such, after retrieving the form from the database, I was ordering the categories and then the questions manually so they could be displayed in the right order.

I am aware that I should not use the entity model for any kind of business logic. I am doing this because it is much more faster to proceed like this since it is something I work on my free time (doing all different business models, entity models and such takes much more time).

At this stage, I am mostly searching for an "easy" solution, even if not perfect. If it is a solution that take more time than reverting to .NET6, it is a good start there :)

Here is the code I have right now for that problem:

```
public async Task<GetApprovalFormResponse<GetStaticErrorType>> GetAsync(GetApprovalFormRequest request)
{
    var form = await storage.ApprovalForms
        .Include(s => s.ApprovalSections).ThenInclude(s => s.ApprovalQuestions)
        .Where(s => s.IdApprovalForm == request.IdApprovalForm)
        .FirstOrDefaultAsync();

    if (form == null)
    {
        return new GetApprovalFormResponse<GetStaticErrorType> { Success = false, ApprovalForm = null };
    }

    //We must order the categories and then questions in them
    foreach (var category in form.ApprovalSections)
    {
        form.ApprovalSections = form.ApprovalSections.OrderBy(s => s.Order).ToList();

        foreach (var question in category.ApprovalQuestions)
        {
            category.ApprovalQuestions = category.ApprovalQuestions.OrderBy(s => s.Order).ToList();
        }
    }

    return new GetApprovalFormResponse<GetStaticErrorType> { Success = true, ApprovalForm = form };
}
```

From the look of it (and I had confirmation by looking at this thread first [EF Core 6 to 7 the collections no longer have setters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74599304/ef-core-6-to-7-the-collections-no-longer-have-setters/74599455#74599455)), my issue is the lack of setter after using the scaffolding to generate my models. So, I have to figure a way to work around this new reality.

I do understand I could update the templates but if possible, I am keeping this as a last ressort :)

Also, I understand I could split up the database queries to retrieve them in the right order directly instead of doing this inside the code. Not sure at all of how to do this in one single query thought. It could be a solution to my problem for sure.

At first, I wanted to post a comment on that other thread but it seem I do not have enough reputation for this. I normally read answers and I almost never post stuff myself. I guess I know what I have to do in the future.

Comment: The data layer of your application doesn't care about the order of navigation collections. That's a UI concern. IMHO you shouldn't be replacing the navigation collection anyway as this would prevent the data layer from using more efficient methods for change tracking. However EF 7 does support custom templates for scaffolding, so if you need to do something different, you can.

Comment: In my case, the user on the UI use buttons to reorder. They do not type the position they want the questions so tracking is not that important (where it could be in many other areas).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not direct answer to your question, but you can order in `Include`

```cs
var form = await storage.ApprovalForms
    .Include(s => s.ApprovalSections.OrderBy(x => x.Order))
    .ThenInclude(s => s.ApprovalQuestions.OrderBy(x => x.Order))
    .Where(s => s.IdApprovalForm == request.IdApprovalForm)
    .FirstOrDefaultAsync();
```

Comment: You see, I was not aware at all I could call on the method Order inside the Include. That is definetely worth a try there I would say. I will try it tonight and if it solve my problem, I'll mark your answer as the most useful to me in this scenario.

Comment: It is [documented](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/querying/related-data/eager#filtered-include)